# How do I make a Table's Attribute a Foreign Key within that Table?

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys

I had to write the SQL to create the tables, attributes, and primary & foreign keys in this ERD:
http://imgur.com/VYZbwr6

In the table 'Financial_Transactions' in the ERD there is a attribute called 'previous_transaction_id' and another attribute called 'transaction_id'. In this table 'previous_transaction_id' is a Foreign Key for this table in addition to being an attribute. It references the last 'transaction_id' in the table.

Here is my SQL for the 'financial_transactions' table:

```
CREATE TABLE financial_transactions(
transaction_id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
account_id int NOT NULL,
item_rental_id int NOT NULL,
previous_transaction_id int,
transaction_type_code int NOT NULL,
transaction_date date NOT NULL,
transaction_amount money NOT NULL,
transaction_comment varchar(512) NOT NULL);

ALTER TABLE financial_transactions ADD CONSTRAINT pk_financial_transactions PRIMARY KEY (transaction_id);

ALTER TABLE financial_transactions ADD  CONSTRAINT fk_financial_transactions_accounts FOREIGN KEY(account_id)
REFERENCES accounts (account_id);

ALTER TABLE financial_transactions ADD  CONSTRAINT fk_financial_transactions_customer_rentals FOREIGN KEY(item_rental_id)
REFERENCES customer_rentals (item_rental_id);

ALTER TABLE financial_transactions ADD  CONSTRAINT fk_financial_transactions_financial_transactions FOREIGN KEY(previous_transaction_id)
REFERENCES financial_transactions (previous_transaction_id);

ALTER TABLE financial_transactions ADD  CONSTRAINT fk_financial_transactions_transaction_types FOREIGN KEY(transaction_type_code)
REFERENCES transaction_types (transaction_type_code);
```

When I run my SQL (includes statements for each table in the script) I get these errors:

"Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 87
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'financial_transactions' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'fk_financial_transactions_financial_transactions'.

Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 87
Could not create constraint. See previous errors."

All other statements execute normally.

What am I doing wrong?

*I used this statement originally under CREATE TABLE: previous_transaction_id int NOT NULL,
However, it resulted in the same error and when searching I saw a similar question that was fixed by removing the NOT NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with defining a foreign key to the same table but you have a column referencing itself.

Try replacing:

```
ALTER TABLE financial_transactions ADD  CONSTRAINT fk_financial_transactions_financial_transactions FOREIGN KEY(previous_transaction_id)
REFERENCES financial_transactions (previous_transaction_id);
```

With:

```
ALTER TABLE financial_transactions ADD  CONSTRAINT fk_financial_transactions_financial_transactions FOREIGN KEY(previous_transaction_id)
REFERENCES financial_transactions (transaction_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
ALTER TABLE financial_transactions ADD  CONSTRAINT 
fk_financial_transactions_financial_transactions 
FOREIGN KEY(previous_transaction_id)
REFERENCES financial_transactions (previous_transaction_id);
```

You have a column referencing itself.  Was that your intent or did you want to reference the transaction_id?

Comment: I'm not really sure, I'm relatively new to SQL and this is the first query I've written that did this. I think I want it to reference transaction_id though.

Comment: It's a simple change.  In fact, it's in the other answer.

Comment: +1 I had already spent some time on it, thought I would write the complete answer.